# Time to change the google-webmaster-tools tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retagging

Google renamed Webmaster Tools to Search Console in May 2015. The resolution from [this old question](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1354/tag-google-webmaster-tools-to-google-search-console) was to add `google-search-console` as a synonym, with a view to making it the "master" some time later.

It's now (much) later, is it time to change this tag? [Google Trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%2012-m&q=%22Google%20Webmaster%20Tools%22,%22Google%20Search%20Console%22) suggests that the newer term has now overtaken the old one.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up.   I was thinking just last week that it was overdue by now.

Answer (score 5):

It is time to make the change.   [google-search-console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search-console) should now be the canonical tag.

One of the criteria brought up last time was which is used more.

- ["search console"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22search%20console%22) 50 uses since November 30th.
- ["webmaster tools"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22webmaster%20tools%22) 50 uses since October 27th.

In other words, "search console" is used in questions about 25 times per month and "webmaster tools" is used about 16 times per month.

Comment: This tag rename has now been completed