# Remove "gwt" synonym from "google-search-console" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Looks like "gwt" was a synonym of "google-webmaster-tools", then this was merged into "google-search-console" and now "google-search-console" has "gwt" as a synonym.

But, "GWT" is the official name of "google-web-toolkit" since 2012. So I'm asking to remove the "gwt" synonym so it can be used as it actual meaning, referring this framework: http://www.gwtproject.org/

In StackOverflow "gwt" has this meaning: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gwt/info

Related links:

- [Tag: google-webmaster-tools to google-search-console](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1354/tag-google-webmaster-tools-to-google-search-console)
- [Time to change the google-webmaster-tools tag?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/time-to-change-the-google-webmaster-tools-tag)

Answer (score 3):

After a Google and Bing search, it appears the acronym `GWT` more commonly refers to the `Google Web Toolkit` now that Google re-branded `Google Webmaster Tools` to `Google Search Console`, so the `GWT` tag synonym was removed.

You're free to create the `GWT` tag again, and add *tag info* corresponding to the `Google Web Toolkit` for it.